# Generating TypeScript typings in parcel for scss

Tags: typescript, types, sass, parceljs

From what I gather in [the documentation](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/), this can be done with very little configuration and without a `tsconfig.json`.

The issue I'm trying to resolve is: `Cannot find module './styles.module.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.  ts(2307)`

[image]

This is my project structure:

[image]

What I've tried to do:

- Install `npm i @types/scss-parser --save-dev`
- [Generating Types](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/#generating-typings):

  ```
  {
     ...
       "source": "src/index.ts",
       "module": "dist/index.js",
       "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
     ...
  }
  ```

  But that just gives me: `Error: No transformers found for src/index.html with pipeline: 'types'.`

  Removing `types:` then results in the error: `@parcel/namer-default: Target "module" declares an output file path of "dist/index.js" which does not match the compiled bundle type "html".`

  Changing to `"module": "dist/index.html"` results in: `@parcel/core: Unexpected output file type .html in target "module"... File extension must be .js or .mjs"`

I'm not sure how to resolve the issue then and have a feeling will actually have to make a `tsconfig.json` or a `types` declaration of some kind.

I just wanted to check here before doing that to see if there is a way to resolve this without making additional files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an out-of-the-box way for parcel to generate the necessary `.d.ts` files to provide strong typing for `.scss` modules. The [Generating Types documentation](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/#generating-typings) you linked to above describes how people who author libraries (e.g. npm packages that are published and consumed by others) can use parcel to generate a consolidated `.d.ts` file that describes `.js` bundle generated by parcel, which doesn't sound like your use case.

Fortunately, there is a great tool called [`typed-scss-modules`](https://github.com/skovy/typed-scss-modules) that can generate `.d.ts` files that describe all `.module.scss` files in your project, and it's pretty simple to integrate it into a parcel-based project. Here's what you need to do:

1. Install `typed-scss-modules`:

   ```
    yarn add -D typed-scss-modules
   ```
2. Add a command to your `package.json` that will generate the `.d.ts` files for all `.module.scss` files in your project:

   ```
   "build:scss-types": "tsm src --nameFormat none --exportType default",
   ```

   By default, `typed-scss-modules` will transform the names of the classes defined in `.scss` files to camel case, and remove dashes. This is not the way parcel behaves (it will leave class names untouched). But you can align with parcel behavior using the `--nameFormat none` option.
3. Then, you can import class names into your typescript files like this:

   ```
   import classes from "./styles.module.scss";
   ```

   (Note how this uses the default export, not `import * from` syntax - this aligns with the `--exportType default` option above).
4. Now `VSCode`, `tsc` and `@parcel/validator-typescript` should be happy. You'll get Intellisense, and errors if you ever make a typo referencing a name from the `classes` import.
5. For the best workflow, you might consider adding the `build:scss-types` command to your build and CI pipeline so that you'll get build-time errors if you ever make a naming mistake. You can also run `tsm` with the `--watch` option to re-generate `.d.ts` files automatically during devlopment.

Here is [a repo where this is all working](https://github.com/astegmaier/parcel-scss-ts-test) that you can use as an example.